# Custom TextField with Secure Type On

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have created custom TextField to change placeholder colour & move the text offset little up.

Here code is.

```
-(void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect{

    UIColor *color = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-Medium" size:16];

    UIFont *font = self.font;

    NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     font, NSFontAttributeName,
     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName,color,NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];

    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attrsDictionary];

}

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectInset( bounds , 1 , 5 );
}

// text position
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectInset( bounds , 1 , 5 );
}

- (CGRect)placeholderRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds{

    return CGRectInset( bounds , 1 , 5 );

}
```

Because of custom texfield, when typing on password filed the rounded dots appears small & on return action is become normal.

While Typing

[image]

After typing
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
[image]

> From IOS 7 on words apple provided that functionality we can't do any
>   thing and it's not an issue. its by default functionality for secured
>   textfield.

Comment: If I use default textfield. It appear normal while typing & return

Comment: once see above two images i have added.